# Compute the center and radius of the smallest circle that includes two smaller circles

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I'm trying to find an algorithm that computes the coordinates of the center and the radius of the smallest circle that covers two smaller circles. I know the radius and x, y coordinates of the center of the 2 smaller circles.

I tried this algorithm below, it works even when the two circles overlap or far apart, but that's only if circle1 and circle2 are on the same x or y axis.

Let c1, c2 be circle1 and circle 2;
r be radius:

```
    if c1x >= c2x:
        if c1y >= c2y:
            c = ((c1x + c1r) + (c2x - c2r))/2, ((c1y + c1r) + (c2y - c2r))/2
            r = max(((c1x + c1r) - (c2x - c2r))/2, 
                     ((c1y + c1r) - (c2y - c2r))/2)
        elif c1y < c2y:
            c = ((c1x + c1r) + (c2x - c2r))/2, ((c2y + c2r) + (c1y - c1r))/2
            r = max(((c1x + c1r) - (c2x - c2r))/2, 
                     ((c2y + c2r) - (c1y - c1r))/2)
    elif if c1x < c2x:
        if c1y >= c2y:
            c = ((c2x + c2r) + (c1x - c1r))/2, ((c1y + c1r) + (c2y - c2r))/2
            r = max(((c2x + c2r) - (c1x - c1r))/2, 
                     ((c1y + c1r) - (c2y - c2r))/2)
        elif c1y < c2y:
            c = ((c2x + c2r) + (c1x - c1r))/2, ((c2y + c2r) + (c1y - c1r))/2
            r = max(((c2x + c2r) - (c1x - c1r))/2, 
                     ((c2y + c2r) - (c1y - c1r))/2)
```

Comment: @Selcuk Not a duplicate - this question is much simpler, just elementaty geometry

Comment: Can the smaller circles have different sizes or do they have the same radius?

Comment: @MBo That question explicitly allows - and is answered with - algorithms for two circles only.

Answer (score 1):

Covering circle parameters (pseudocode):

```
dx = c2x - c1x
dy = c2y - c1y
//center-center distance   
dc = Sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)
rmin = Min(r1, r2)
rmax = Max(r1, r2)
if rmin + dc < rmax then
    covercenter = center of larger circle
    R = rmax
else
    R = 0.5 * (r1 + r2 + dc)
    x = c1x + (R - r1) * dx / dc
    y = c1y + (R - r1) * dy / dc
```

work examples (blue is covering):
[image]

Comment: This is inexact if the two circles have different radii. It is also inexact in case one of the circles is enclosed in the other.

Comment: @Reblochon Masque I thought that radii are the same, thanks

Comment: I think you should state that your answer uses pseudocode, as the question is about Python.

Answer (score 0):

If your algo works when both centers have same `x` or same `y`, then you could replace `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` by `(0, 0)` and `(sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2), 0)` (just applying the appropriate translation and rotation on the plane).

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the **DRY** principle (Don't repeat yourself) in your code and don't duplicate your formulas multiple times. You're going to make copy-paste errors or forget to modify one of the copies.

I'm grouping all those variations of the formula together by sorting the small circles so that I can directly access e.g. the leftmost circle's x (`cax`) and its radius (`caxr`) or the lowest circle's y (`cby`) and its radius (`cbyr`).

```
from math import sqrt

(cax, caxr), (cbx, cbxr) = sorted([(c1x, c1r), (c2x, c2r)], key=lambda t:t[0])
(cay, cayr), (cby, cbyr) = sorted([(c1y, c1r), (c2y, c2r)], key=lambda t:t[0])

x = (cax-caxr + cbx+cbxr) / 2
y = (cay-cayr + cby+cbyr) / 2

r = sqrt( ((cax-caxr) - (cbx+cbxr))**2 + ((cay-cayr) + (cby+cbyr))**2 ) / 2
```

[See this code running on IDEone.com](http://ideone.com/UNWA81)